# Spring boot creating configuration files when it should not

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot

I have excluded all DB related autoconfiguration in my spring boot application. But still it is trying to create JdbcTemplateConfiguration and failing not not finding any DataSources.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
JmsAutoConfiguration.class, MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class,
DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Stacktrace

```
Error - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]: Factory method 'jdbcTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
```

Comment: Add your actual application class and not only an annotation and also add to your question *which* Spring Boot version you are using.

Comment: Additionally provide also your classpath dependencies configuration (e.g. Maven or Gradle file)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot Docs describe [3 Spring Boot mechanisms how to configure `dataSource` bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource):

1. Embedded database -> just add embedded DB engine to classpath
2. Standard SQL data source -> configure JDBC access in configuration file
3. JNDI DB access -> also configured via configuration file

Additionally you can configure your `dataSource` bean explicitly by standard Spring IoC mechanisms.

Your error indicates that non of these constructs for defining `dataSource` bean exist in your application.